# How to use datepicker in mvc 3 EditorFor?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

i have 2 important question.

1) DateTimePicker is working good on `<input type="text" name="date" id="date"/>`  but no css effect and color.
2) `<%Html.EditorFor(m => m.StartDateTime, new { @class = "datepicker" })%>` is not working. No show datetimepicker.

How to make jquery datetimepicker. My Referenced article is : http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2010/02/05/mvc-2-editor-template-with-datetime.aspx

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../Styles/jquery.ui.all.css"  type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js") %>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js") %>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker.js") %>"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.datepicker').datepicker({});
        $('#date').datepicker({});

    });
</script>





<table>
<tr><td><input type="text" name="date" id="date" /></td></tr>
<tr><td><%:Html.LabelFor(m=>m.StartDateTime) %></td><td><%:Html.EditorFor(m => m.StartDateTime, new { @class = "datepicker" })%></td></tr>
</table
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

programmerist, here's how i did this a little while back.

Create the editorfor template with the name DateTime.aspx:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<DateTime?>" %>

<%string name = ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix;%>
<%string id = name.Replace(".", "_");%>

<div class="editor-label">
    <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model) %>
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    <%= Html.TextBox("", (Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") : string.Empty), new { @class = "date" }) %>
    <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model)%>
</div>      

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#<%=id%>").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            showOn: 'button', 
            buttonImage: '<%=Url.Content("~/Content/images/calendar.gif") %>'
        });
    });
</script>
```

then simply call it as such in your view:

```
<%= Html.EditorFor(m => m.StartDate) %>
```

cheers...

Answer (score 3):

For your second problem, use Html.TextBoxFor instead of EditorFor to get the html attributes.

```
Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Date, new { @class = "datePick", Value = Model.Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") })
```

For your first problem, is your path correct?  I use Url.Content to get it

Answer (score 1):

**Try using Html.TextBoxFor instead of Html.EditorFor:**

```
<%:Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StartDateTime, new { @class = "datepicker" })%>
```

For CSS issue, use:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<%= Url.Content("~/Styles/jquery.ui.all.css") %>"  type="text/css" />
```